# ¿porque mi boton de save no funciona, si el campo imagen es opcional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Etoy haciendo el front de una aplicacion en React y al agregar imagenes el boton save del `MOvieForm` dejo de funcionar por mas de que puse el campo imagen como opcional.
tambien tengo un arreglo de imagenes donde esta el metodo `saveMovie(movie)` para guardar las pelis y hago uso de este pero no me esta funcionando me doy cuenta porque al apretar el boton save la pagina deberia redirigirme a /movies y guardar la peli nueva pero no lo esta haciendo.

```js
import React from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import Form from "./common/form";
import { getMovie, saveMovie } from "../services/fakeMovieService";
import { getGenres } from "../services/fakeGenreService";

class MovieForm extends Form {
    state = {  
        data: {
            title: "",
            genreId: "",
            numberInStock: "",
            dailyRentalRate: "",
            img: ""
          },
          genres: [],
          errors: {}
    }

    schema = {
        _id: Joi.string(),
        title: Joi.string()
          .required()
          .label("Title"),
        genreId: Joi.string()
          .required()
          .label("Genre"),
        numberInStock: Joi.number()
          .required()
          .min(0)
          .max(100)
          .label("Number in Stock"),
        dailyRentalRate: Joi.number()
          .required()
          .min(0)
          .max(10)
          .label("Daily Rental Rate"),
        img: Joi.string().allow('').optional()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const genres = getGenres();
        this.setState({ genres });
    
        const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;
        if (movieId === "new") return;
    
        const movie = getMovie(movieId);
        if (!movie) return this.props.history.replace("/not-found");
    
        this.setState({ data: this.mapToViewModel(movie) });
    }
    
      mapToViewModel(movie) {
        return {
          _id: movie._id,
          title: movie.title,
          genreId: movie.genre._id,
          numberInStock: movie.numberInStock,
          dailyRentalRate: movie.dailyRentalRate,
          img: movie.img
        };
    }
    
      doSubmit = () => {
        saveMovie(this.state.data);
        this.props.history.push("/movies");
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className = "container">
              <div className = "height"></div>
              <div className = "card card-login card-hidden">
              <div className = "card-header card-header-primary text-center">
                <h4>Movie Form</h4>
              </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className = "card-body text-center p-4">
          {this.renderInput("title", "Title")}
          {this.renderSelect("genreId", "Genre", this.state.genres)}
          {this.renderInput("numberInStock", "Number in Stock", "number")}
          {this.renderInput("dailyRentalRate", "Rate")}
          {this.renderButton("Save")}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default MovieForm;
```

Este es my arreglo de peliculas, aqui pueden hecharle un ojo al metodo `saveMovie(movie)` porque seguro algo me esta faltando ahi, el arreglo es muy largo mejor les muestro solo el metodo de save.

```js
export function saveMovie(movie) {
  let movieInDb = movies.find(m => m._id === movie._id) || {};
  movieInDb.title = movie.title;
  movieInDb.genre = genresAPI.genres.find(g => g._id === movie.genreId);
  movieInDb.numberInStock = movie.numberInStock;
  movieInDb.dailyRentalRate = movie.dailyRentalRate;
  movieInDb.img = movie.img;

  if (!movieInDb._id) {
    movieInDb._id = Date.now().toString();
    movies.push(movieInDb);
  }

  return movieInDb;
}
```

Comment: ¿a que te refieres que el botón dejó de funcionar? ¿no aparece? ¿al apretarlo no hace nada? ¿te arroja un error? ¿qué error? podrías poner algunos `console.log` o `debugger` en tu función `saveMovie` para ver por consola los valores que estás usando. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya me parecia que habia algo raro con el boton y no con el metodo porque no me marcaba ningun error, resulta que tenia el type del boton puesto en `button` pero debia ser `submit`, esto claro en form.jsx que no muestro aqui pero tengo en mi proyecto, lo siento fue un error estupido puesto que el componente `MovieForm` renderiza un formulario.

```js
  renderButton(label) {
      return (
      <button 
      type="submit"
      disabled = {this.validate()}
      className="btn btn-primary">{label}
      </button>
      );
    }
```